# 8086 emulator for unix-like OSs?

Tags: fedora, x86, emulation, assembly

Is there any 8086 emulator (free or paid) for Fedora 17? I am learning assembly language using AT&T style.

Comment: You don't really need an emulator for that unless you don't have an x86/x86_64 machine. All you need is an assembler if you do.

Comment: agree. but emulator can quicken the learning when you can see data moving in and out of the registers, instruction by instruction.

Comment: Not really, you'd be better off using a debugger for that.

Comment: Should this be a community wiki question?

Comment: @EvanTeitelman No. Community wiki basically just invites unmaintained lists of random links. If the question seems too broad or otherwise like there's no real correct answer, it should be closed.

Comment: @Mat After assembling the code using an assembler like `as -march=i8086` how/where do I run that binary since I don't have 8086 processor? Wouldn't I need 8086 emulator for that?

Answer (score 8):

Here are two 8086 emulators:

- [i8086emu](http://i8086emu.sourceforge.net/) - A cross-platform emulator
  for the Intel 8086 microprocessor. It has support for dynamically loadable
  device plugins and some peripherals like a PIT, PIC, 8-segment-displays,
  buttons and leds. i8086emu comes with an ncurses and an GTK-2 gui.
- [fake86](http://fake86.rubbermallet.org/) - An 8086 PC emulator written in
  C. It seems to have less device support than i8086emu.

Answer (score 3):

There is [Bochs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochs) kind of oldest virtual machines.

Off-course, you must check [Qemu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU) project. It is a mainstream **open-source** virtual emulator.

You can always nag the thing what you need and make a contribution to the project's core.

Comment: Both Bochs and QEMU virtualize the entire environment, which might not be what the OP is after.

Comment: "8086 emulator (free or paid) for Fedora 17"

Comment: Exactly. A virtualized computer environment is a lot more than the CPU.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any hypervisor software.for example:Qemu-kvm,Virtualbox,Xen,Vmware and so on.
    I suggest that  you  use qemu-kvm or virtualbox to launch a virtual machine. Because qemu-kvm and virtualbox are open source hypervisor,and they are easy to use.Virtual box has a good GUI that written by QT. Qemu-KVM has a powerful command line.
   Libvirt is also a good command line to support all hypervisor.Specially support qemu-kvm.
   You can do every things in vm.If your vm crashs,your host will not be affected.

Comment: I have the same comment on this as on [@innocent-world's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87596/2465): there is a lot more to a virtualized computer environment than just the CPU. And if software running inside any sort of emulator can crash bringing anything on the host along with it, something is horribly broken in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

PCEm does a great job emulating the full hardware: https://pcem-emulator.co.uk/

if you live in Windows only world then 86box (fork of PCEm) may interest you: https://github.com/86Box/86Box

They do not only emulate the CPU but a whole lot of hardware including voodoo 3dfx etc

check some posts who have played with these: https://virtuallyfun.com/wordpress/category/80386/

and you can check pcem forums to use with Linux https://pcem-emulator.co.uk/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=3155